# need to delete selected rows through checkbox with a single Delete button

Tags: php, jquery

okay this is the updated main php page now, ive cleared my previous post to make this clean, FYI...what im posting here are just my test page which is he exact replica of my actual page..just have different php page name...

```
    <link href="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" ></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SMP1_deletefromDB.js"></script>
    <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#results").show();
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#RetrieveList").on('click',function() {
                var xid = $('#XiD').val();
                var date = $('#Date').val();
                $.post('resultgenerator_test.php',{xid:xid, date:date}, function(data){
                $("#results").html(data);
                });
                return false;
            });
             });

        //post to delete.php file. In delete.php you can get the id's in $_POST['id'] as multidimensional array. You can handle the delete operation based on that
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#DeletefromDB").on('click',function() {
         //get all the checked values from checkboxes
         var ids = $('input[name=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {
             return this.value;
         }).get(); 

         if (ids.length === 0) 
             return false; //show some error message

         //post to delete.php file. In delete.php you can get the id's in $_POST['id'] as multidimensional array. You can handle the delete operation based on that
         $.post('deletedata.php',{id : ids}, function(data){
         $("#results").html(data);
             //handle the message based on success or error
         });

          return false;
    });
     });

    </script>

    </head>

    <body class="oneColFixCtrHdr">

    <div id="container" style="width:auto">
      <div id="header" style="background-color:#7BD12E">
        <h1 align="left" style="color:#FFF; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">PIS  Ticket Tracking System</h1>
      <!-- end #header --></div>
       <div id="mainContent">
        <h1 style="font-size:9"></h1>
        <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
          <p>
            <label for="Back"></label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" name="Back" id="Back" value="Back To Main" href="#" onclick="return backAway();" />
          </p>
        </form>
        <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">

          <table width="741" border="0" align="center">
            <tr>
              <th colspan="9" align="center" style="font-size:12px" scope="col">Xid, Name:<span>
                <select name="XiD" id="XiD">

                  <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
                  <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
                  <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
                  <option value="DDD">DDD</option>
                  <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
                  <option value="FFF">FFF</option>
                  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                </select>
              </span><span style="font-size:12px">
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="date">Date:</label>
              <input type="text" name="Date" id="Date" />
              </span></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="9" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th colspan="9" scope="col">
                <div align="center">
                  <input name="action" type="button" id="RetrieveList" value="Retrieve List" />
                  <input name="action" type="button" id="DeletefromDB" value="Delete from DB" />
                  <input name="Clear" type="reset" id="Clear" value="Clear" />
                </div>
                <label for="Clear"></label>
                <div align="center"></div></th>
            </tr>

          </table>
    </form>
        <div id="results">
        </div>
      </div>
```

and here is my 2nd php page that echoes the data into table format: Please read my comments below as I need it to clarify...

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery("input[name=checkall]").click(function () {
    jQuery('input[name=checkall]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    jQuery('input[name=checkbox]').prop('checked', this.checked);
  });


  // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
  // and viceversa
  jQuery("input[name=checkbox]").click(function(){

    if(jQuery("input[name=checkbox]").length == jQuery("input[name=checkbox]:checked").length) {
        jQuery("input[name=checkall]").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        jQuery("input[name=checkall]").prop("checked", false);
    }
  });
});

</script>
<?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$xid = $_POST['xid'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$sql="SELECT ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name 
        FROM tbl_main
        WHERE employee_id_name = '" . $xid . "' AND resolved_date = '" . $date . "'";
$myData = mysql_query($sql);



echo "<table width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' border=1 align='center'>
<tr>
<th align='center'><input id=checkall name=checkall type=checkbox value='' /></th>
<th align='center'>Remedy Ticket No.</th>
<th align='center'>Phone/Incident No.</th>
<th align='center'>Category 2</th>
<th align='center'>Category 3</th>
<th align='center'>Status</th>
<th align='center'>Create Date</th>
<th align='center'>Severity</th>
<th align='center'>Ban Type</th>
<th align='center'>Resolved Date</th>
```

//***I have added this header so that im fetching the employee_id_name as well but just hiding it so i can delete it from my 3rd php...i used the following but still showing a very small cell on the Xid column...***

```
<th align='center' style='display:none'>XiD</th>
</tr>"; 


while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) 
{ 
echo "<form action='resultgenerator_test.php' method='post'>";

echo"<tr>"; 
echo "<td align='center'>" . "<input type=checkbox name=checkbox value=" . " </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['ars_no'] . "<input type=hidden name=ars_no value=" . $info['ars_no'] . " </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['phone_number'] . "<input type=hidden name=phone_number value=" . $info['phone_number'] . " size='11' maxlength='11' /> </td>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['category_1'] . "<input type=hidden name=category_1 value=" . $info['category_1'] . "' /> </td>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['category_2'] . "<input type=hidden name=category_2 value=" . $info['category_2'] . "' /> </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['status'] . "<input type=hidden name=status value=" . $info['status'] . "' /> </td>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['create_date'] . "<input type=hidden name=create_date value=" . $info['create_date'] . "' /> </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['trouble_type_priority'] . "<input type=hidden name=trouble_type_priority value=" . $info['trouble_type_priority'] . " size='1' maxlength='1' /> </td>"; 
echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['ban_type'] . "<input type=hidden name=ban_type value=" . $info['ban_type'] . " size='1' maxlength='1' /> </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . "<input type=text name=resolved_date value=" . $info['resolved_date'] . " size='8' maxlength='8' /> </td>";
echo  "<td align='center'>" . "<input type=hidden name=employee_id_name value=" . $info['employee_id_name'] . "' /> </td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
echo "</form>";
} 
echo "</table>"; 

include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

now look at the 3rd php page that ive created as u suggested and explained...please correct if u see any errors on the code:

**LATEST UPDATE delete php:**

```
<?php
require 'include/DB_Open.php';

$id = $_POST['id'];
$idtodelete = "'" . implode("','",$id) . "'";

$query = "DELETE FROM tbl_main WHERE ars_no in (" . $idtodelete . ")";
$myData = mysql_query($query);

include 'include/DB_Close.php';
?>
```

thanks for all the help...:)

Comment: show us your full code, where is that code for check box?

Comment: Why do you say that `DeletefromDB` button is not working?

Comment: DeletefromDB button is not working coz i dont know how a 2 submit button in a single form would co-exist and i also dont know how to pass the selected rows to the DeletefromDB button so it can be deleted...hope this is clear.

Comment: @dencioyap : So far, You don't have any trouble with server side. right?

Comment: nope server side is good...

Comment: do you have more than one row in return?, In that case you are using your form in a wrong way. In your code the form tag will be generated more than once. And also using form tag between rows will cause design issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you need to do is to handle the update and delete operations with the submit button name. What you need to do is to create two submit buttons with same name but different values.

This is your form :

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input name="action" type="submit" id="RetrieveList" value="RetrieveList" />
    <input name="action" type="submit" id="DeletefromDB" value="DeleteFromDB" />
    <input name="Clear" type="reset" id="Clear" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

I have given same name `action` for the two `submit` buttons. Once this form is submitted you can check the `$_POST['action']` in the server side.

You can do it like:

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'RetrieveList') {
    //retreive list functionality
} elseif ($_POST['action'] == 'DeleteFromDB') {
    //delete from dB functionality.
}
```

**UPDATE:**

You need to change your form like this :

```
echo "<form action='resultgenerator.php' method='post'>";
    echo '<input name="action" type="submit" id="DeletefromDB" value="Delete from DB" />';
    echo "<table width='auto' cellpadding='1px' cellspacing='0px' border=1 align='center'>
            <tr>
            <th align='center'><input id=checkall name=checkall type=checkbox value='' /></th>
            <th align='center'>Remedy Ticket No.</th>
            <th align='center'>Phone/Incident No.</th>
            <th align='center'>Category 2</th>
            <th align='center'>Category 3</th>
            <th align='center'>Status</th>
            <th align='center'>Create Date</th>
            <th align='center'>Severity</th>
            <th align='center'>Ban Type</th>
            <th align='center'>Resolved Date</th>
            </tr>"; 

    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($myData)) { 
        echo"<tr>"; 
            echo "<td align='center'>" . "<input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' value='add the id here which needs to be deleted'/></td>";
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['ars_no'] . "<input type=hidden name=ars_no value=" . $info['ars_no'] . " </td>";
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['phone_number'] . "<input type=hidden name=phone_number value=" . $info['phone_number'] . " size='11' maxlength='11' /> </td>"; 
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['category_1'] . "<input type=hidden name=category_1 value=" . $info['category_1'] . "' /> </td>"; 
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['category_2'] . "<input type=hidden name=category_2 value=" . $info['category_2'] . "' /> </td>";
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['status'] . "<input type=hidden name=status value=" . $info['status'] . "' /> </td>"; 
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['create_date'] . "<input type=hidden name=create_date value=" . $info['create_date'] . "' /> </td>";
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['trouble_type_priority'] . "<input type=hidden name=trouble_type_priority value=" . $info['trouble_type_priority'] . " size='1' maxlength='1' /> </td>"; 
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . $info['ban_type'] . "<input type=hidden name=ban_type value=" . $info['ban_type'] . " size='1' maxlength='1' /> </td>";
            echo  "<td align='center'>" . "<input type=text name=resolved_date value=" . $info['resolved_date'] . " size='8' maxlength='8' /> </td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
    } 

    echo "</table>";

echo "</form>";
```

Now in your **resultgenerator.php** file you can check :

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'DeleteFromDB') {
    $ids_to_be_deleted = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : array();
    //$ids_to_be_deleted will contain all the checked id's from the other page. You can get all those values in the array. Handle the remaining operation for delete here.
}
```

**NEW UPDATE :**

So if you are using jQuery to submit your form, then it would be better to change the form submit binding to click function on the button. You can change your form to :

```
  <link href="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/css/dark-hive/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js" ></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="SMP1_deletefromDB.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#RetrieveList").on('click',function() {
            var xid = $('#XiD').val();
            var date = $('#Date').val();
            $.post('resultgenerator.php',{xid:xid, date:date}, function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });

        $("#DeletefromDB").on('click',function() {
            //get xid for delete like you do above. create a page delete.php or something and make an ajax call to some page to delete data
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</head>

<body class="oneColFixCtrHdr">

<div id="container" style="width:auto">
  <div id="header" style="background-color:#7BD12E">
    <h1 align="left" style="color:#FFF; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">PIS  Ticket Tracking System</h1>
  <!-- end #header --></div>
   <div id="mainContent">
    <h1 style="font-size:9"></h1>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
      <p>
        <label for="Back"></label>
        <input type="button" name="Back" id="Back" value="Back To Main" href="#" onclick="return backAway();" />
      </p>
    </form>
    <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">

      <table width="741" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <th colspan="9" align="center" style="font-size:12px" scope="col">Xid, Name:<span>
            <select name="XiD" id="XiD">

              <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
              <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
              <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
              <option value="DDD">DDD</option>
              <option value="EEE">EEE</option>
              <option value="FFF">FFF</option>
              <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            </select>
          </span><span style="font-size:12px">
          <label for="date">Date:</label>
          <input type="text" name="Date" id="Date" />
          </span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="9" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="9" scope="col">
            <div align="center">
              <input name="action" type="button" id="RetrieveList" value="RetrieveList" />
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="action" type="button" id="DeletefromDB" value="DeleteFromDB" />
              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input name="Clear" type="reset" id="Clear" value="Clear" />
            </div>
            <label for="Clear"></label>
            <div align="center"></div></th>
        </tr>

      </table>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form>
    <div id="results">
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Here What I have done is changed the binding event on form submit and binded on click event of input type buttons. I changed type submit to button.

Now you can check on the click event of each buttons and handle the operations.

**UPDATE:**

Assuming that you have the retrieved list in your results div. When the user check the checkboxes and click the delete button you can handle it using this script:

```
$("#DeletefromDB").on('click',function() {
     //get all the checked values from checkboxes
     var ids = $('input[name=checkbox]:checked').map(function () {
         return this.value;
     }).get(); 

     if (ids.length === 0) 
         return false; //show some error message

     //post to delete.php file. In delete.php you can get the id's in $_POST['id'] as multidimensional array. You can handle the delete operation based on that
     $.post('delete.php',{id : ids}, function(data){
         //handle the message based on success or error
     });

      return false;
});
```

**UPDATE :**

This can be your **delete.php** file

```
$ids = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';

if (!empty($ids)) {
   //implode the id's separated by commaas
   $ids_to_be_deleted = implode(',', $ids);

   $query = "DELETE FROM your_table WHERE field_to_be_checked IN ($ids_to_be_deleted)";
   //now run your query using mysql_query

}
```

**NB:** : mysql* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [**MySQLi**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: thank you Sabari...but how can i pass the selected rows to the Delete button so the delete button would work when clicked.

Comment: @dencioyap Can you post your full form which contains the delete and retrieve list buttons

Comment: @dencioyap You just have a form with three buttons only. From where are you taking values then ?

Comment: ah...i have another php which runs the query its the 3rd code that i've posted above...just exactly below the code that uv created for me for the checkboxes...

Comment: @dencioyap so you are saying that you want to submit the 3rd form on update or delete button click ?

Comment: so basically what it does is when i click the Retrieve button on the first code...it will call my second php which will then run the query and echo into table form...now what i need to know is how to pass the result back to the Delete button so it can be deleted if needed.

Comment: @dencioyap what you mean by passing the value back to delete button. You have the delete button on the first page right. What value are you passing for retrieving the list

Comment: forget the update and delete button that will be created on each row..ive changed my plan to just have a single Delete button that will delete all selected rows and possibly just use an Update button in the future...and that Delete button is what u see now on the first code...

Comment: @dencioyap iF you want to delete the complete list using the delete button, then put the complete table inside one form. Currently you are using forms for each table row. Then add the id to be deleted as value to checkbox, then select the checkboxes using the jQuery method and then submit using the delete button

Comment: what i mean by passing the value back to the delete button are the rows that will be selected thru the checkbox...so once i selected a rows thru checkbox...i want the Delete button to know which row is selected and then execute the deletion of that row/s...that script to delete the selected rows is what i dont have yet...thanks

Comment: OK so what I am saying is to put all your table data inside one form and add the id of the thing you want to delete as checkbox value and change the name to checkbox[] to make it an array. So once you submit the form you will have the id's in $_POST['checkbox'] as an array.. Hope this is what you want

Comment: yep ur right its exactly what i need but im not sure how exactly i can code that...since i have already used two php page that would work as one...i would appreciate if u can enlighten me on that...

Comment: Hi Sabari..sorry  for d late reply...i just woke up...i tried ur suggestion and am getting this error: Notice: Undefined index: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\resultgenerator.php on line 40

Comment: Hi Sabari...code already updated above...it shows my entire code for my two php page now...

Comment: @dencioyap I think this should work. add the two codes. I will check

Comment: @dencioyap your form appears to be different from what I have posted. Can you check that

Comment: yep so ur proposed code doesn't seem to work...but yeah that last update was the code that i really have...thanks

Comment: @dencioyap your code seems to be different from the one I proposed, the code which you have updated here is different from that. Actually you want the delete button in the main php page or the 2nd php page.  am bit confused on that. I wrote the delete for 2nd php page, but your code seems to be different from that

Comment: @dencioyap any update on this? If you can give me some more info on the above, I can get you the correct one

Comment: sorry...im actually in the office now...i want it in the main php page where i originally have it...

Comment: so retrieve and delete button would actually be on the main php page so that's where i asked if two submit button would work on a single form which then u gave an advise to make the name similar for both retrieve and delete...

Comment: @dencioyap you are saying you want it in the first form right

Comment: @dencioyap How are you redirecting to retreive list page. You are submitting your form1 on the same page right ?

Comment: yes u r right, i want the Delete button in the first form, and here is how i use Retrieve button, im binding the Date and Xid together with the 2nd form to get the result...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#form2").bind('submit',function() {
            var xid = $('#XiD').val();
            var date = $('#Date').val();
            $.post('resultgenerator.php',{xid:xid, date:date}, function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

Comment: so what actually happens when i click the Retrieve button is it would include the Date and Xid to my query, so much like the code below then it will echo the result in the main page

$xid = $_POST['xid'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$sql="SELECT ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type 
        FROM tbl_main
        WHERE employee_id_name = '" . $xid . "' AND resolved_date = '" . $date . "'";
$myData = mysql_query($sql);

Comment: all of the codes that i commented here are actually included in my codes on top

Comment: hey mann...thanks for the update...so the Retrieve button still works...but i just dont get what u said here: "get xid for delete like you do above. create a page delete.php or something and make an ajax call to some page to delete data"

can i not just call whatever is echoed by my second php page which has the primary key of "ars_no" and sent it to the delete button?

Comment: @dencioyap For deleting the data you may create another page like the one you created 2nd php page. Post the data in to that page like you do the same for 2ndphp page. So in delete.php you will get the Xid and handle the delete operations there.

Comment: nice idea though it does not match what i want to happen...what i want is that after my main php called the 2nd php to echo the query then i can check or select a row to be deleted...then i would pass it to my delete button so i can delete it...

Comment: @dencioyap then what you want to do is that. Hide the delete button list the list or html is populated in the page. Once the list is populated using Retreive List button click, show the delete button. So when the user selects the check boxes and click on the delete button, then get all the checkbox values with jQuery and then using ajax delete the values. Hope you understand

Comment: hehehe...as much as i want to understand it but with my little knowledge i just cant comprehend...can u please...please give me rough sample of the code that i can follow...my aplogies...if i have taken so much of ur time...thanks in advanced...

Comment: arrrggg...my tiny php knowledge is killing me...im getting the idea but i dont know how to do this: "In delete.php you can get the id's in $_POST['id'] as multidimensional array. You can handle the delete operation based on that"...i dont know how to create a SQL DELETE function with multidimensional array...sorry...

Comment: thanks for ur update again...
just have some few questions...my Retrieve button does not work after i change from "submit" to "button" type.
then what d u mean by $ids_to_be_deleted and WHERE field_to_be_checked, if what i want to be deleted are rows that were selected or checked thru checkbox...should i just be using the id of my checkbox?
how can i send u a screenshot of my php so at least u have an idea of how it looks like and how it should work

Comment: @dencioyap Did you write the click function for the retrieve list button, Check whether the id of the button and id in the click function are same. $("#RetrieveList").on('click',function() {. THis is the current click function. Check one of my update above for this. $ids_to_be_deleted means the id's which are to be deleted from dB. It contains the values of checkboxes you selected separated by commas. field_to_be_checked is your dB fields against which the checkbox id's are to be checked.

Comment: hello...i was able to create my 3rd php page now and edited some on my previous pages...please check as my Delete button still does not work....and also i've corrected my error on the Retrieve button now...its already working...i just missed this }); part...hehe

Comment: @dencioyap In the above posted html, it seems that the result div is missing. Also delete.php ajax call will only go when you select any checkbox. If you have missed something can you post the correct html. also in your first php file, there is <script>

if ($_POST['action'] == 'RetrieveList') {
    //retreive list functionality
} elseif ($_POST['action'] == 'DeletefromDB') {
    //delete from dB functionality.
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#results").show();
});
</script> . Why ther is php variable inside script. Remove that it is wrong. It is showing error

Comment: i have added the missing result div now...also i removed the php variable inside the script but that was how my onclick would select either bet Retrieve and Delete button,right? so where should i be putting it...do i need to add a php to my main page?

Comment: @dencioyap Why do you need php checking condition inside script. We are checking on onClick.. so you do we need php post actio '

Comment: oh okay...i didn't know that we need to stash it...understood now...but can u please check if i made my delete php code correct coz nothing happens when i try to delete...

Comment: @dencioyap is the ajax call working.. means is it going to delete.php page ?

Comment: @dencioyap your delete.php is wrong.. Which column does the check box id's we are passing implies

Comment: i dont think ajax call to delete php is working coz its not doing anything when Delete button is click...and on my table that was echoed by my 2nd php...there is a column for checkbox...u made it working for me on my other question...but i dont know how to pass to my column fields?theres just a plain checkbox at the leftmost...thats it...

Comment: @dencioyap Check the network tab of your browser to see if the ajax call is being made ... your delete.php is also wrong

Comment: ill try to check the network tab...but what is wrong with my delete php?

Comment: @dencioyap $query = "DELETE FROM tbl_main WHERE (ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name) IN ($ars_no, $phone_number, $category_1, $category_2, $status, $create_date, $resolved_date, $trouble_type_priority, $ban_type, $employee_id_name)"; this wrong.. echo it out and try running in phpmyadmin you will know

Comment: to answer ur question if ajax call is being made for the Delete button..nope its not...im getting 404 not found under Status...

Comment: @dencioyap so ajax call is made, but the url may be wrong then

Comment: hey mann, i got it to call the delete page now but im getting this errors: "Warning: implode() expects at most 2 parameters, 11 given in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\Dennis\deletedata_test.php on line 33" and lots of Notice: Undefined variable: error...any idea how i can correct that?

Comment: i think i've fixed this error: "Warning: implode() expects at most 2 parameters, 11 given in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\Dennis\deletedata_test.php on line 33" already...just left with lots of Notice: Undefined variable: error which im still trying to figure out how to fix...

Comment: @dencioyap implode the id's only you are imploding the fields.. that is the error..what is the undefined error ?

Comment: yep, understood...those are the id's already that i implode and its already fixed...just need to fixed the Notice: Undefined variable: error...im getting it from this line:"IN ($ars_no, $phone_number, $category_1, $category_2, $status, $create_date, $resolved_date, $trouble_type_priority, $ban_type, $employee_id_name)";"

Comment: This wrong .. DELETE * FROM yourtable where your id IN  ($ids_to_be_deleted).. You should do like this.. Check my last update

Comment: here's how my entire code looks like: $query = "DELETE FROM tbl_main WHERE (ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name) IN ($ars_no, $phone_number, $category_1, $category_2, $status, $create_date, $resolved_date, $trouble_type_priority, $ban_type, $employee_id_name)";
$myData = mysql_query($query);
};...what i have pasted above is the line where im getting the undefined variable error

Comment: @dencioyap this is wrong .It should be like this $query = "DELETE FROM tbl_main WHERE  your id only IN ($ids to be deleted) ";

Comment: okay...this is how my delete query looks like now...please advise if this is correct..."$query = "DELETE FROM tbl_main 
        WHERE (ars_no, phone_number, category_1, category_2, status, create_date, resolved_date, trouble_type_priority, ban_type, employee_id_name)
     IN ($ids_to_be_deleted)";

Comment: no this is wrong. Give only the id that is related to $ids_to_be_deleted

Comment: what id are u referring to here...looking at my codes...those seem to be my id's...

Comment: in this one $ids_to_be_deleted) represent which column in your table ?

Comment: thats exactly what i wrote in my code...those are the id's of my each column that needs to be deleted...

Comment: @dencioyap the $ids_to_be_deleted will all be of one column right.. how will it come across multiple columns ? the id's are coming from checkbox.. It will be of a single column only

Comment: sorry for all the confusion...can u do a final check on my delete php to see if i learned something from this conversation of ours...

Comment: @dencioyap  is checkbox  your column in the table ?

Comment: @dencioyap Cool what was that one ?

Comment: Hello, i was able to make it as simple as my latest update above...hehe...by the way..ive created a code that would give me an alert to validate prior to deleting and to confirm after deleting but it doesnt seem to work...can u take a look at it maybe u can help me fixed it as well...here is the title "alert message after delete not working properly"

Answer (score 1):

For your first concern, give the same name to both your submit button (e.g: 'action'), and on the server side after submit check the value : `if ($_POST['action'] == 'Retrieve List') {} else if ($_POST['action'] == 'Delete from DB')`

Second concern, the name of the checkbox is the key :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{$info['ars_no']}"/>
```

Then on server side :

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but can u please help me identify where to put both of this in to my php 

"if ($_POST['action'] == 'Retrieve List') {} else if ($_POST['action'] == 'Delete from DB')"

and this: "foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) {}"

Comment: The `if ($_POST['action'] == '')` goes on the form validation php. When equals 'Retrieve List' put the retrieve list code that seems to work. When equals 'Delete from DB' then you execute the loop `foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) { // delete }` OR if you want to delete from database you can execute `mysql_query('DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']).')');`. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dropdown list where you can chose if you want to retrieve or delete:

```
<select name='choseaction'>
<option value="RetrieveList">Retrieve List</option>
<option value="DeletefromDB">Delete from DB</option>
</select>
```

And then use a single submit button.

```
<INPUT TYPE ="Submit" Name ="Submit" VALUE ="Submit">
```

After that you can verify like this:

```
  if ($_POST['choseaction']=='RetrieveList')
   {
   ...
   } else if ($_POST['choseaction']=='DeletefromDB')
     {
     ...
     }
```

Hope this helps! 
Good day.